# autologin to website with angularJS form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autologin

I have a website with angular JS authentification form, 
I need to autologin to this site with Javascript

The form is like :

```
<form name="loginForm" class="login-form ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
    <div class="tight-form ng-scope" ng-if="loginMode">
        <ul class="tight-form-list">
            <li class="tight-form-item" style="width: 78px"><strong>User</strong></li>
            <li><input name="username" 
                class="tight-form-input last ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" 
                required="" ng-model="formModel.user"  placeholder="email or username" style="width: 253px" type="text">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tight-form ng-scope" ng-if="loginMode">
        <ul class="tight-form-list">
            <li class="tight-form-item" style="width: 78px"><strong>Password</strong></li>
            <li><input name="password" class="tight-form-input last ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" 
                    required="" ng-model="formModel.password" id="inputPassword" style="width: 253px" 
                    placeholder="password" type="password"></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
<div class="login-submit-button-row">
    <button type="submit" class="btn ng-binding btn-inverse"  ng-click="submit();" 
    ng-class="{'btn-inverse': !loginForm.$valid, 'btn-primary': loginForm.$valid}">Log in</button>
</div>
</form>
```

PS : I have no inputs Id, just Names

I have tried to autologin with javascript, i created a bookmark in my navigator with url :

```
javascript:document.getElementsByName('username').item(0).value='MYloginValue';document.getElementsByName('password').item(0).value='MypasswordValues';void(0);
```

But it did not work.

I'm not familiar with Angular JS

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it with DOM, do it within your controller.

For instance

```
login($scope.username, $scope.password)
```

Ensure that these fields are bound using angular data-binding!

Best,

Comment: My controller ? The auth form is on an external website, i can't edit it.
Can you clarify more please